# CMake: choosing to load shared library at runtime

Tags: c++, c, cmake, clang

I have a set of shared libraries, and want to choose between which one to load at runtime depending on the device that the program is running on.

One of the shared libraries is built as a target in my CMakeLists, and that target also includes the required headers to interface with the different libraries. The other shared libraries will have already been built, and the `.so`s will be in a known location at runtime.

I'm trying to find a solution where I can use the headers from the shared library target, but choosing which shared library to actually use at runtime.

Is this possible?

Comment: Explicit dynamic loading means resolving everything via dlsym and casting the result to a function pointer typedef that matches the function signature. Can be really annoying for a large library with lots of functions.  The workaround to this is to have the SO library export a factory function that returns a pure virtual C++ interface to the caller than wraps all the calls. Such that the only dlsym call you make is for obtaining this factory function. Does this make sense?

Comment: Build the executable to depend on a library at a specific path. Build a second executable (or shell script) that examines the host system, sets a symbolic link at that path to point to the desired library, and launches the primary executable. The link might instead be adjusted by a login shell script or a script run when the system starts up, as appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Portably? No. Delayed runtime linking to shared objects is a platform feature on Windows, so you could pull it off there without modifying the C/C++ code of your application much.

Otherwise, the only semi-portable method of doing it is by forcing runtime resolution of library symbols, so you first open the library you want using `dlopen` or `LoadLibrary` and then look up symbols in it, and convert them to data or function pointers of appropriate type.

In C++, to make your life easier, it's possible for the pointers to assume types from the library headers, so there's less potential for typos:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>

// This declaration lives in some library header
void * LIB_fun_1(int, char *);


void test()
{
    auto libhandle = dlopen(...);
    if (!libhandle) abort();
    // here, pLIB_fun_1 will have a proper type for calling LIB_fun_1,
    // using decltype<&LIB_fun_1>
    auto pLIB_fun_1 = 
        reinterpret_cast<decltype(&LIB_fun_1)>(dlsym(libhandle, "LIB_fun_1"));

    // pLIB_fun_1 can be used here

    dlclose(libhandle);
}
```